# Convert 3 2D-curves to a 3D-curve and How to calculate weight value of the animation curve in Unity?

Tags: c#, beziers

I have 3 Hermite curves, including a position at the x, y, and z axes controlled by tangent and weight values. I knew that it is a 2D curve. now I can calculate the tangent from 1st derivative, but the weight is what I cant know how to convert from 2D curve to 3D Bezier curve.

And vice versa, I have a 3D Bezier curve, and I want to convert from 3D bezier curve to 3 2D curves, here is the code I calculate tangent.

```
float CalTangent(float t) 

      { return a * (-3f * t * t + 6 * t - 3) + b * (9 * t * t - 12f * t + 3f) + c * (-9f * t * t + 6f * t) + d * (3f * t * t); }
 
float outTangent = CalTangent(t);
float inTangent = CalTangent(t1);
```

With a, b, c, d are 4 points that control bezier 3D, does anyone know how to calculate the in/out weight values?

Here is the example that I want to do, convert each other between 3 2D curves (red, green, blue) and the 3D curve (black).
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RA1e.png

Comment: We have [previous Q&A about converting between Hermite and Beziér expressions of a spline](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/179407/39518). The X Y and Z curves of either spline are just the X Y and Z components of the 3D spline. The 2D curves you describe are just the XY, YZ, and XZ components of the 3D spline. No conversion necessary, just delete the unwanted axis. If that's not what you need, you'll need to edit your question to describe your situation in more detail.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not simple as that, when the weight value of one of 3 anim curve is not the same as the rest, it works so wrong
https://imgur.com/a/O537NwC

Comment: This image example is not legible. You may want to use a higher resolution, or avoid low-contrast colours like red on grey that image compression algorithms love to smear.

Comment: I'm so sorry that not confirmed it sooner. I asked Freya Holmer, maybe you know her.
She told that there's no way when using a custom weight, it's no longer a cubic bezier curve, so we couldn't composite three non-cubic, non-polynomial, 1D bezier into a cubic polynomial 3D bezier
By the way, thank you so much for your care, only you answer my question :3

Comment: Want to delete this question then?